# Understanding a Docker .Sh file

Tags: docker

The .sh file I am working with is:

```sh
docker run -d --rm -it --gpus '"device=0,1,2,3"' --ipc=host -v $HOME/Folder:/Folder tr_xl_container nohup python /Path/file.py -p/Path/ |& tee $HOME/Path/log.txt
```

I am confused about the `-v` and everything after that. Specifically, the `-v $HOME/Folder:/Folder tr_xl_container` section and `-p/Path/`. If someone would be able to help breakdown what those commands mean or point me to a reference that does, that would be very much appreciated. I checked Docker documentation and Linux command line documentation and did not come up with anything too helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A `docker run` command is split up in 3 parts:

- docker options
- the image to run
- a command for the container

In your case `-d --rm -it --gpus '"device=0,1,2,3"' --ipc=host -v $HOME/Folder:/Folder` are docker options.

`tr_xl_container` is the image name.

`nohup python /Path/file.py -p/Path/` is the command sent to the container.

The last part, `|& tee $HOME/Path/log.txt` isn't run in the container, but takes the output from the `docker run` command and saves it in `$HOME/Path/log.txt`.

As for `-v $HOME/Folder:/Folder`, it's a volume mapping or more precisely, a bind mount. It creates a directory in the container with the path `/Folder` that is linked to the directory `$Home/Folder` on the host machine. That makes files in the host directory visible inside the container and if the container does anything with files in the /Folder directory, those changes will be visible in the host directory.

The command after the image name is for the container and it's up to the container what to do with it. From looking at it, it looks like it runs a Python program stored in `/Path/file.py` in the image. But to be sure, you'll need to know what the image does.

Comment: The image runs a Python script so that all checks out. I appreciate the clarification